# apt, apt-get, pkg, dpkg, etc, not found in Pydroid3 terminal

Tags: android, python-3.x, linux, termux, pydroid

### In [Termux](https://termux.com/)

I learnt to use ***apt*** and ***pkg*** in Termux to install & manage packages.

```
-$  apt install tree
-$  apt remove tree
-$  pkg install tree
-$  pkg uninstall tree
-$  pkg install mariadb
-$  dpkg, apt-get, etc...
```

`Everything worked fine`

---

### In [Pydroid3](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ru.iiec.pydroid3) terminal

So, i just tried the same in Pydroid3 terminal.

```
/storage/emulated/0 $  apt install tree
sh: apt: not found

/storage/emulated/0 $  pkg install tree
sh: pkg: not found

/storage/emulated/0 $  apt-get
sh: apt-get: not found

/storage/emulated/0 $  dpkg
sh: dpkg: not found
```

`Only pip and some basic commands work here`

*Pydroid3 terminal details :*

```
/storage/emulated/0 $  uname -a
Linux localhost 4.14.113-21094692 #1 SMP PREEMPT Thu Feb 25 17:48:28 +07 2021 aarch64 GNU/Linux
```

---

### On Internet

When I searched the web, I found that maybe these commands are not installed on the linux distribution of Pydroid3.

---

### What to do?

How can I install all these package-managers in Pydroid3 terminal?

*Or*

Are there some different ways to install and manage packages there?

*Or*

Is there any other problem?

Note : my android device is not rooted

Comment: Is pydrod even built to do things like that? I thought it was only for learning and running python 3 code

Answer (score 0):

You were able run and install those Termux packages mentioned because Termux devs built (**port**) this packages for arm devices and other android cpu s and made them available through repositories hosted on **Bintray**.

```
https://dl.bintray.com/termux/termux-packages-24/{archurl}
```

Pydroid itself comes pre-built with some command line pacakges but doesn't host additional repositories which Termux does with its **apt** and **pkg** package managers.

The best you could compile this pacakges yourself if you have the source as pydroid comes with various command line compiler **cc**, **c++**,**cmake**, **gfortran**.

Another options is to use the **pip** package manager to install Python wrapper for some c libraries Pydroid offers.

All the best - **Happy Coding!**