# How to install apt or pkg in Pydroid 3

Tags: android, apt, dpkg, termux, pydroid

I want to install `apt` or `pkg` package manager and `Termux` repositories (`main-repo`, `root-repo`, `x11-repo`) on `Pydroid 3`. How can I do this? Help me please!

Comment: This question is already been answered [there.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67026579/apt-apt-get-pkg-dpkg-etc-not-found-in-pydroid3-terminal)